# Converting float to hexadecimal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So, I'm trying to convert this Scratch program to a python program: http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/1963078/#editor. I am currently using it with pattern 3. Here's what I have:

```
from turtle import*
import random
import math
turtle = Turtle()
bgcolor("#000000")
ht()
speed(0)
goto(0,0)
def draw():
    x1 = (random.randint(0,250))
    y1 = (random.randint(0,250))
    x2 = (random.randint(0,250))
    y2 = (random.randint(0,250))
    counts = 0
    while counts < 250:
        count = 0
        while count<250:
            c = (math.tan(math.sqrt(((xcor() - x1)**2) + ((ycor() - y1)**2))))*(math.tan(math.sqrt(((xcor() - x2)**2) + ((ycor() - y2)**2))))
            color(c)
            setx(xcor+1)
            count += 1
        counts +=1
draw()
```

I know a lot of people use python 2, but I'm using 3. The problem right now is that when it uses that long line to generate a color, it's returning a decimal number, when I need to be getting a hex code. Any tips on how I would convert that to get a result like the scratch project? Thanks!

Comment: Why not produce the 3 colour components separately? You can pass in a `(r, g, b)` tuple or three separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any standard method for converting a floating point / decimal number to hex (usually hex is only used for positive integers)… so you'll have to decide how you want to convert the decimal to a positive integer.

BUT, once you've got a positive integer, you can convert that to an RGB hex color (ex, `#AABBCC`) using:

```
>>> some_number = 123456
>>> hex_color = "#%06X" %(some_number, )
>>> print hex_color
#01E240
```